# How to mutate the state of an array in graphql?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

I am trying to add an array inside a GraphQl schema. Currently, it looks like this:

```js
type Play {
  winRatio: [Float]
}
```

The purpose of the win ratio is to hold the history of all win ratios. For example, after 3 games, the winRatio array should look like this:

```js
winRatio: [1, .5, .66]
```

Currently, when I mutate the winRatio array, no history is saved; the state updates to the latest value. This is how that looks:

```js
await API.graphql({
  query: updatePlay,
  variables: {
    input: {
      winRatio: [winRatio, (await wins) / (await totalPlays)], // update the player's win ratio
    },
  },
})
```

However, when I query for the winRatio data in graphql, I get an array with ONLY the latest value:

```js
winRatio:[.66]
```

I feel like I need the spread operator, but I am not sure why my current solution is not solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct in that you need the spread operator.

```js
winRatio: [...winRatio, (await wins) / (await totalPlays)]
```